# Storing clipboard contents in database and restoring it

Tags: c#, database, ms-word, store, clipboard

I am trying to write a program that is supposed to store a collection of paragraphs containing text, images, formulas and etc in database. Afterwards, the program must be able to select some of those paragraphs, put them together and prints on paper.

My idea was typing each paragraph in ms-word, copying the paragraph in clipboard and then saving the clipboard contents in a database record via my application. Then inside the application I can select some of those records, merge, and place them back in the clipboard. Then, if I paste the clipboard contents in ms-word I get the selected paragraphs and I can print them using ms-word.

I tried Clipboard.GetText and Clipboard.SetText. Also I tried pasting the paragraphs in a ritchText control in my application and saving its rtf contents but none of them worked. I also read similar questions but couldn't manage to solve the problem.

Any ideas is highly appreciated.

Comment: Copying to clipboard is going to be unreliable. You could face threading issues and data is easily corrupted when setting/getting data from the clipboard across two applications. I recommend you save the paragraph to a txt file and have your application read and save from there.

Comment: Might be more helpful if you posted the code that didnt manage to solve the problem and we could help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Save the topics to a text files and have the program read the paragraphs then add them to the correct fields.

Comment: juanvan's solution is not useful because paragraphs do not contain only plain text, but complex formulas, images, graphs and etc. Based on Dunbar's recommendation, I decided to avoid using clipboard approach. I found that I can easily type each paragraph as a separate word file then merge them using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly. I did some initial tests based on [this](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Document-merging-in-CNET-734.php) and [this](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2007/05/23/how-to-merge-multiple-microsoft-word-documents-in-c.aspx) and they worked! thx to all